# IndexError: list index out of range with threading

Tags: python, multithreading

I am trying to run a function for a specific period of time during n seconds. However getting an indexError. Been trying several to solve the issue for several hours but I can't seem to find what is going wrong. Below is the and sample code.

```
def recognize_face_time(i):
global dirname
imageList = list(paths.list_images(dirname))
#print(imageList)
print("[INFO] loading encodings...")
data = pickle.loads(open("encodings.pickle", "rb").read())
# load the input image and convert it from BGR to RGB
image = cv2.imread(imageList[i])

rgb = cv2.cvtColor(image, cv2.COLOR_BGR2RGB)
# detect the (x, y)-coordinates of the bounding boxes corresponding
# to each face in the input image, then compute the facial embeddings
# for each face
print("[INFO] recognizing faces...")
boxes = face_recognition.face_locations(rgb,
    model="hog")
encodings = face_recognition.face_encodings(rgb, boxes)
# initialize the list of names for each face detected
names = []

# loop over the facial embeddings
for encoding in encodings:
    # attempt to match each face in the input image to our known
    # encodings
    matches = face_recognition.compare_faces(data["encodings"],
        encoding, tolerance=0.45)
    name = "Unknown"

    # check to see if we have found a match
    if True in matches:
        # find the indexes of all matched faces then initialize a
        # dictionary to count the total number of times each face
        # was matched
        matchedIdxs = [i for (i, b) in enumerate(matches) if b]
        counts = {}
        # loop over the matched indexes and maintain a count for
        # each recognized face face
        for i in matchedIdxs:
            name = data["names"][i]
            counts[name] = counts.get(name, 0) + 1
        # determine the recognized face with the largest number of votes 
        name = max(counts, key=counts.get)

    # update the list of names
    names.append(name)

i += 1
x = threading.Timer(1, recognize_face_time, [i])
x.start()


#test_names.append(names)

if i == 4:
    x.cancel()
    #print(test_names)
```

Here is the error I am having

```
image = cv2.imread(imageList[i])
IndexError: list index out of range
```

Comment: Any chance of reducing that to a [mcve]?

Comment: What are `imageList` and `i` just before that statement is executed? What happens if you just call that function with `i` in the main thread or from a shell prompt?

Comment: If you are using an IDE that has debugging features, now might be the time to learn them.

Comment: You probably exceed the range of the list. What's the value of i and the state of the list before the function execution ? plus, make your code look normal and minimalize it to the important piece

Comment: The value of i is 0 and is passed as argument to the function. I am using Sublime text editor and no IDE. Also I have included the whole piece of code since everything seems to work fine with minimal code. However, while trying to run the whole function, i does not seem to increment and just outputs the error stated above.